# SQL query, information in a specific period from current date

Tags: sql

Hi guys hope you can help, I've done a search but can't seem to find what I'm looking for...

I'm trying to write a SQL query to show me all employees that have started 12 weeks or 84 days from the date of running the query (current date). I've got this so far but it's not returning the results I was expecting, I'm getting some records through where the start date is older than 84 days.

`.... WHERE (EmployeeJobs.DateTo IS NULL or EmployeeJobs.DateTo = dateadd(d,datediff(d,0,getdate()),84))`

I need a NULL statement included as unfortunately not all the records have a date in them.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you have a DateFrom and a DateTo field?  And the range of those two dates shows that they were employed between those two dates?  Where a NULL DateTo means they have not yet left?  And you want people who were employed 84 days ago?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, its suitable for all versions of Sql Server 2000+

```
....
WHERE
  (EmployeeJobs.DateTo IS NULL
   or
   CONVERT(varchar, EmployeeJobs.DateTo, 112) = CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(d,-84,GETDATE()), 112)
  )
```

**BUT** if you running it @ sql server 2008+ you can simplify the work:

```
....
WHERE
  (EmployeeJobs.DateTo IS NULL
   or
   cast(EmployeeJobs.DateTo as DATE) = CAST(dateadd(d,-84,GETDATE()) as DATE)
  )
```

**OR** with the possibility of using index

```
....
WHERE
  (EmployeeJobs.DateTo IS NULL
   or
   EmployeeJobs.DateTo >= CAST(dateadd(d,-84,GETDATE()) as DATE)
   AND
   EmployeeJobs.DateTo < CAST(dateadd(d,-83,GETDATE()) as DATE)

  )
```

Comment: Converting to string for purpose of comparing is evil and will cause a scan.

Answer (score 1):

```
where
  EmployeeJobs.DateTo IS NULL
  or
  datediff(d, EmployeeJobs.DateTo, getdate()) = 84
```

If you're using SQL Server 2008, then

```
where
  EmployeeJobs.DateTo IS NULL
  or
  cast(EmployeeJobs.DateTo as date) = cast(getdate() - 84 as date)
```

Comment: @aF. Don't think so. There's an `=` in the question, and it needs `employees that have started 12 weeks or 84 days from the date of running the query`, which I took as the exact single day.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
WHERE
  (EmployeeJobs.DateTo IS NULL
   or
   convert(varchar, EmployeeJobs.DateTo, 112) = convert(varchar, DATEADD(day, -84, getdate(), 112)
  )
```

Comment: Not answering the question - need the only date which 84 days before

Comment: @OlegDok if it's from 84 ago, it's done then.. That wasn't what I understood in the first place.

Comment: still error, try this - SELECT 1 WHERE CAST('2011-10-14 15:00' AS DATETIME) = DATEADD(day, -84, getdate()) / the TIME matters

Comment: @OlegDok indeed, I got another solution, no more time! :) ok just seen now that you put the same one :P nice taught!

Comment: Yup, that works, but see comments to mine and @GSerg note about indexed

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a DateFrom and a DateTo field? And the range of those two dates shows that they were employed between those two dates? Where a NULL DateTo means they have not yet left? And you want people who were employed 84 days ago?

```
WHERE
      (EmployeeJobs.DateFrom <= dateadd(d, datediff(d,0,getdate()) - 84, 0))
  AND (EmployeeJobs.DateTo   >= dateadd(d, datediff(d,0,getdate()) - 84, 0) OR EmployeeJobs.DateTo IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (as functions are used already the impact on performance is there):

```
WHERE
 -- get difference in days
 DateDiff(dd,
  -- lower date, replace Nulls
  IsNull(EmployeeJobs.DateTo, GetDate()),
  -- highest date
  GetDate()
 )
 -- whatever the criteria, in this case equal to exact 84 days
 = 84
```

Comment: Many thanks guys, as is always the way something else has come up so this report is on hold for now, i`ll give all the above a try when i get back to it.